# What is the earliest that a PC can gain invisibility?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-levels, invisibility

What is the earliest level that a player character (PC) can gain the ability to become invisible without the aid of external items/scrolls/etc.?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## Level 1

[Vanish](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/v/vanish/) is a spell that Wizards, Bards, Magi, and Psychics can use. Because it's a level 1 spell, all those classes can cast it at level 1 to become invisible for 1 round.

That's not for long, but Arcanists, for example, can boost this spell with Arcane Reservoir if they want to prolong it, perhaps becoming invisible for 3 rounds. If you build for it, for example, if you take the [Spell Specialization](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/spell-specialization/) and [Spell Focus](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/spell-focus) feats and combine it with the [Potent Magic](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/arcanist/arcane-exploits/potent-magic-su/) Arcanist Exploit, you can reach maximum duration right at level 1, and become invisible for 5 rounds. I don't know why one would do that, but you might be interested that it's at least possible.

Answer (score 18):

Duergar can cast it as a racial spell like ability once per day from the beginning, level one:

> **Invisibility Spell-Like Ability (Sp)**: A duergar can use invisibility once per day, using its character level as its caster level and affecting itself only.

Source: *Pathfinder Roleplaying Game Advanced Race Guide* © 2012, Paizo Publishing

Answer (score 2):

The Inquisitor [Clandestine Inquisition](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/inquisitor/inquisitions/inquistions-paizo/clandestine-inquisition/) allows you to turn invisible as a standard action lasting as many rounds as your level.  You can use it 3+WIS times per day.  So in theory, at 1st level, with a 16 in WIS you could use your standard action every round and move around invisible for 6 rounds.